# Erro: 102 executar query via MsExecAuto

Tags: advpl

Tenho pouca experiência em `advpl`. Estava estudando o assunto e estou com um probleminha. Obtenho o `erro 102` quanto tento incluir um cadastro na tabela clientes direto no `Protheus`.

Tentei incluir um cadastro via `SQL SERVER` e fui bem sucedido. Consigo conferir que o registro foi incluído na tabela, mas quando abro o `totvs` não localizo nenhum registro. Qual a razão disto acontecer?
Agradeço desde já!

Segue o erro:

```
> Exceção ocorrida: : Error : 102 (37000) (RC=-1) - [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
> Server Driver][SQL Server]Sintaxe incorreta próxima a ''. ( From
> tMSSQLConnection::GetQueryFile ) Thread ID [8376] User [wdrik]    IO
> [13168]   Tables [9]  MaxTables [9]   Comment []  Status []   SP [ ]  Traced
> [No]  InTran [Yes]    DBEnv [MSSQL/P11]   DBThread [(SPID 53,54)] Started
> [02/10/2016 21:07:38] LastIO []   IP [127.0.0.1:1234] RCV [118535]    SND
> [501865]  TCBuild [20141119]   SELECT DISTINCT Z90.Z90_DESCRI,Z92.* FROM
> Z90990 Z90 , Z92990 Z92 WHERE  Z90.Z90_FILIAL = '  ' AND
> Z90.D_E_L_E_T_= ' ' AND Z92.Z92_FILIAL = '  ' AND Z92.D_E_L_E_T_= ' '
> AND Z92.Z92_EST IN ('SP' ) ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Protheus cria diversos controle como o R_E_C_N_O_, na tabela, ao inserir dados via SQL direto você terá problemas.
De fato, você deveria utilizar a Rotina Automática do MATA010 para inserir dados na SA1.

Pele erro que você postou, parece ser erro de alguma tabela de complemento.

Answer (score 0):

As vezes tenho problemas com alterações direto no banco, em alguns casos reiniciar o **dbAccess/TopConnect** resolve o problema, *mas cuidado com alterações por fora, é uma prática não recomendada*. Caso não resolva, delete o registro pelo banco (não esquecer de dar update no **RECDEL**, se existir) e faça a inclusão ou pela rotina automática, como o amigo comentou, ou vá no **APSDU** e inclua manualmente.

Answer (score 0):

Olá Amigo o erro está na sintaxe executada:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT Z90.Z90_DESCRI,Z92.* FROM Z90990 Z90 , Z92990 Z92 
WHERE   Z90.Z90_FILIAL = '  '   AND
        Z90.D_E_L_E_T_= ' '     AND 
        Z92.Z92_FILIAL = '  '   AND 
        Z92.D_E_L_E_T_= ' '     AND 
        Z92.Z92_EST IN ('SP' ) ''
```

Percebe que no fim da query sobram aspas ?, veja a variável que trata a query e ajuste estes caracteres sobrando.

Um detalhe, sempre que faço chamada de query direta faço da seguinte forma:

```
cQuery := " UPDATE " + RetSqlName("ZBR")
cQuery += " SET ZBR_STATUS = '2' "
cQuery += " WHERE ZBR_DATA = '"+DTOS(_dDataPr)+"' "
cQuery += " AND ZBR_INTER  = '11' "
cQuery += " AND D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "
nRet := TcSqlExec( cQuery )
If nRet == 0
    // Deu certo
else
    // Faz algo se der errado
Endif
```